# Updating Data GridView using the selected value inside the dropdown list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist and a `gridview`.. Dropdown list contains the list of the tables I have in my database. What I want is, when I select a particular table name from the dropdownlist, I want all the columns and data inside that particular table display inside the `gridview`.

This is my code...
Code for displaying the list of tables inside the dropdown is success.. But to bind the columns and data inside the `gridview` is not success..
Please Help me...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "table_name";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "table_name";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Employee;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name='+ DropDownList1.selecteditem.text +'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        //+DropDownList1.selecteditem.text +
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea on several levels. First you are wide open to SQL injection. Second, you are giving everyone full view access to every column and row of every table.

But the reason you are not getting data is because the select string does not make sense. It should look like this

```
"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'"
```

But this is how a proper sql connection should look like.

```
//create a new datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//create the string that hold the query including token
string query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = @TableName";

//create a new database connection
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    //replace the token with the correct value
    command.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

    //open the connection
    connection.Open();

    //load the data of the select into the datatable
    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());

    //bind the datatable to the gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    //but you can also skip the datatable and bind directly to the gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```